# Insulating a roof with no felt lining

Tags: insulation, roof

I am buying a 50s property that has no felt lining underneath the roof tiles. The tiles are concrete and there are a couple of loose tiles so going to get those fixed asap. I am wondering what kind of insulation would be suitable for a non felted roof. I'm aware that ventilation in this type of roof is key so don't want to overdo it.
There is currently a thin layer of insulation wool laying on the floor of the loft but that it is. Could i increase the thickness of that insulation wool or would this be an issue with ventilating the roof?

Answer (score 2):

The felt is an additional barrier to water infiltration and has nothing to do with insulation.

If you have a ventilated attic, then don't add any insulation on the interior side of the roof -- the roof is supposed to be cold, and the thermal envelope for the property is located just above the ceiling, which I assume is the area you are calling a "loft" with some wool insulation. This is where you'd add extra insulation. How much depends on your climate zone, and different materials have different R-values.

If you have a "hot roof" (the thermal envelope is just below the roof), then you can add insulation between the rafters. But this does not seem to be your case.